# Channel with URLs based on entry type

Tags: url, entry-type, channels

Example: I have content which could be separated into `Big News` and `Small News`.

The Big News has much text (which would need a link to its own entry). The Small News has only one text block (so it wouldn't need a separate page for each news).

Whats the best way of handling this? Two separate channels?

One channel with two entry types and a template with a conditional:

`{% if entry.type == 'SmallNews' %}{% exit 404 %}{% endif %}`

How do you handle this? I guess it is not possible to add `These entries have their own URLs` based on entry types, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make this decision based on what makes the most sense for the client. You can realize both solutions on a technical level, so it's really just a question about the preferable CP user experience.

For me this sounds like "Big News" and "Small News" are quite similar, so I'd probably like to have them combined in a single channel. And your template conditional is a good way to handle the manually (accidential?) typed in URLs.

You could even add a dedicated source for the entry index views by making use of the `modifyEntrySources` hook and some lines of custom plugin code. See this Stack Exchange Q&A for how to do this: [Filter entries by entry type in the CP?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/11791/125)

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with the 404 conditional then. I prefer a simple and easy CP for my clients.